# laravel: update or create (upsert) for pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

Is there a Laravel (i.e. easy) way to perform an upsert on a pivot table?

I'm using the following code:

```
        if ($mpi->sites()->where('site_id', $site_id)->exists())
        {
            $mpi->sites()->updateExistingPivot($site_id, ['pivot_data'=>$pivot_data]);
        }
        else 
        {
            $mpi->sites()->attach($site_id, ['pivot_data'=>$pivot_data]);
        }
```

What I want is something like this:

```
$mpi->sites()->updateOrAttach($site_id, ['pivot_data'=>$pivot_data]);
```

My Mpi model looks like this:

```
class Mpi extends Model
{

    public function sites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Site")->withPivot('site_mrn');
    }

    .....
```

Comment: Guess you should have a look at `sync()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations  `$mpi->sites()->sync($site_id, ['pivot_data'=>$pivot_data]);`

Comment: so, the prolem with `sync()` is that it will delete the other related records. Another alternative is `syncWithoutDetaching()` which throws an error if the related record already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [newPivotQuery](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_newPivotQuery) witch Create a new query builder for the pivot table

```
$mpi->sites()->newPivotQuery()
          ->updateOrInsert(['mpi_id'=>$mpi->id,'site_id'=>$site->id]
          ,['mpi_id'=>$mpi->id,'site_id'=>$site->id,'pivot_data'=>$pivot_data]);
```